# Let $A = QR $ be a reduced QR factorization. Why is the null($R$) $\subset$ null($A$)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In a proof I am reading it was glossed over as obvious, yet I fail to see why this is.

Comment: Just follow the definition. Take an arbitrary element $x$ of $\text{null}(R)$. What can you say about $x$?

Comment: Ahh I feel foolish...$Rx = 0 \Leftrightarrow QRx = 0$.

Comment: Yes. Don't worry. You can answer the question yourself below so it doesn't come up as answered. Or just delete the question, if you wish.